# Formatting output of grep from fileA: match1 fileA: match2 into fileA: match1 match2?

Tags: unix, grep

I'm using grep to find matches in files inside a folder:

```
grep -inrw "Bob" 'Folder'
```

and I got:

```
Folder/content/fileA.txt:12:    Bob was a good person
Folder/content/fileA.txt:18:    Bob is now even better
```

I know I can only list file names using the `-l` parameter, however if there's a way to format the output in a way, that the file name only appears once for all matches in the file, something like:

```
Folder/content/fileA.txt:
12: Bob was a good person
18: Bob is now even better
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the output using `awk`.

```
grep -inrw Bob * |awk -F: '!a[$1]++ {print $1 FS} sub($1 FS, ""){print $0}'
```

The first condition means if the first column is met for first time. In that case print it. And the last one removes the first column (filename) and the FS `:` and prints a new line with the rest of the content. This cover cases where character `:` exists in the matched lines of `grep`.

example

```
> cat file
Bob line
Bob: Hi there
```

output

```
file:
1:Bob line
2:Bob: Hi there
```

---

Another way is to run `grep -l` and then print the filename and the `grep` output with your parameters.

```
for f in `grep -l Bob *`; do echo $f':'; grep -inrw Bob $f; done
```

Comment: Thanks, however there are cases where the matched line itself has ':' in it, which is also used as a field separator for `awk`, as a result, it only prints out the first component before `:`, is there any workround?

Comment: Yes, you are right! character `:` can exist in the last field, I will update the answer now.